# Fatal error: Uncaught exception too long

Tags: php, exception

I'm using `throw new Exception(...)` to handle errors, but these errors are huge! With 7 stack traces I get a 5 line error.

Let's say I call for a property that doesn't exist. I want to simply display the `property X doesn't exist` message, and the location where it was called: `in file.php, line Y`

Is that possible?

Comment: What are you doing to catch the exception? Your solution will lie there.

Comment: I'm not catching it, I just throw it :)

Comment: The stacktrace is for debugging in development, or post-mortem of errors in production only. It shouldn't really matter that they are long. Might be nice to look at it in a non-HTML / plaintext context though, it's formatted pretty readable. If you're not catching it, you can configure [your own exception handler](http://www.php.net/set_exception_handler)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you simply want this for your own personal debugging. You could do a few things:

a) Learn how to read the exception errors

b) Create an exception handler and only output a few things:

```
set_exception_handler(function(Exception $e)
{
  echo $e->getMessage(); 
  // echo out whatever you want to see
  die();
});
```

Reference [the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php) to see what information is available.

c) Use an extension like xdebug that already provides a pretty exception handler

Comment: +1 Exactly. Note that you can also use `$e->getFile()` and `$e->getLine()` if you want.

Comment: @OZ_, exceptions are preferable to `die("BAD ARG")` or no error handling at all. ;) @lonesomeday, I added a link to the manual that should help.

Comment: @konforce, exceptions is almost same as `die`. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/81567/is-exception-handling-in-php-greatly-overrated-closed

Comment: @OZ_, I agree that if you throw exceptions that you know you aren't going to handle, then it's the equivalent of a `die()`, but you get the added bonus of being able to set a global exception handler and get a more detailed (which line, etc) output. I don't consider exceptions to be the end-all of error handling, but they are very useful for many applications.

Comment: @konforce, exceptions are useful very rare. Currently it's just new toy in PHP and each one tries to play with this toy. I gave you link where you can read good explanation of using Exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Use [trigger_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trigger-error.php) and [set_error_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) , and you'll be able to know LINE and FILE (in handler function).
Also, in handler you can call [debug_backtrace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) and read all information that you need.